# Android TV-box experience.

Tags: android, television

I need to develop Android TV-Box (android device, which use TV, as the screen) app.

Anyone done this? I can not find a good example to understand all the intricacies of this interaction. Maybe you will be able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking IP TV-BOX, then Android is a good choice if your streaming media solution is not that complex.

If you are going to do DVB TV-BOX with Android, you have to consider a lot more like CA, DVB tuner, DVB player etc.

Comment: all what I know about target device - it's "Android device that use TV as the screen". And that's all. And I am only interested in the possibilities and limitations of building UI.

Comment: That is just a OTT box. We have just done one of this little box. We have a fling mouse to control the cursor on the screen. The mouse is using the wireless connection and with a motion detector inside. And if you want to do something fancy, I encourage you to integrate openNI.

Comment: thanks for answer. I will only be at the disposal of the TV remote.

Comment: Then the android will support your remote by native. You shall just move your focused indicator and map all the remote keys with standard android key code.

Comment: thanks for great news. and my last question - do you know any examples or apps with open source code, or similar apps in android market?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a share-able one. But I think you might refer the design of GoogleTV.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only difference is that you will have different input peripherials. You don't have touch screen, don't have keyboard. Rather, you'll have Bluetooth and network connections. The UI is the same as for mobile devices.

And of course, you won't have ScreenOrientationChange :)

Comment: thanks for answer. I am of the same opinion, but I hope there are people who are experts in this and they know a little more information